# What happens to DynamoDB stream when we convert regional table to global table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am trying to convert my existing DynamoDB table to a global DynamoDB table.

In the existing DynamoDB table structure, we have configured a DynamoDB Stream that triggers a Lambda function when there is a change in DynamoDB data.

What will happen to the DynamoDB Stream when I convert the table to a global DynamoDB table? Will the new DynamoDB replicas have their own DynamoDB streams or will the DynamoDB Stream be present only in the original region where the table was first initialized?

Will converting the DynamoDB table to a global table have any effect on DynamoDB Streams that trigger the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All replicas will have streams enabled. As for your Lambda trigger, that's up to you.

1. You can just have the Lambda in a single region, as you do now and it will fire for all modification, no matter what region the write was to.
2. If you need a Lambda to fire only for each individual region, then you can create a Lambda per region and use Lambda Event Filters to filter it to fire only when the write occurred in the local region. To do so with DynamoDB, you'll need to add the region as an attribute to your item.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html

Answer (score 0):

Stream events will fire locally in all regions, as each region accepts the write or the replicated write.

Comment: But what if I need to trigger lambda only in one region? what will happen to the stream events triggered in other regions? @hunterhacker

Comment: They will trigger in both regions. As a workaround, some people create an attribute on insert holding the local region name and then event filter so as to only run lambdas on items where that attribute is the local region. Works well for inserts and updates, just not deletes.